# .Net RSA verification of data signed by OpenSSL

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, rsa

I have a situation where I generate a 2048 bit RSA public / private key pair.  The public key is copied to a client computer (Windows) while the private key is kept on a server (Linux).  I want the server to be able to generate a signature on a block of data using the private key then send the signature, and the block of data, to the client so that the client can verify the signature using the public key.

This is how the key is being generated:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
openssl req -subj "/C=GB/ST=ST/L=L/O=Org/OU=Unit/CN=cert name/emailAddress=nothing@nowhere" -new -x509 -key private.key -out publickey.cer -days 3650
openssl pkcs12 -passout pass:mypassword -export -nokeys -out public.key -in publickey.cer -inkey private.key
```

This creates two key files, private.key (the combined public and private keys) and public.key (the public key).

The client application is in C#.  There, I load the public key like this:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\public.key", "mypassword");
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
```

This works fine for encryption because if I encrypt a block of data and send it to the server on a socket connection then the server can decrypt it and correctly display the data contents.  So I am confident that the key is being loaded correctly.

When the server gets the encrypted block of data, and correctly decrypts it, it then signs a response and sends it back to the client:

```
// Send a signed reply
unsigned char *signature = (unsigned char *) malloc(RSA_size(privateKey));
if (signature != NULL)
{
    char *reply ="Top of the morning to you";
    unsigned int siglen;
    if (RSA_sign(NID_sha1, (unsigned char *)reply, strlen(reply), signature, &siglen, privateKey))
    {
        printf("SigLen = %d\n", siglen);
        unsigned char *msg = (unsigned char *)malloc(siglen + strlen(reply));
        if (msg != NULL)
        {
            memcpy(msg, signature, siglen);
            memcpy(msg+siglen, reply, strlen(reply));
            send(sock, msg, siglen + strlen(reply), 0);
            free(msg);
        }
    }
    free(signature);
}
```

The client receives the data and separates out the signature from the data being signed and then tries to verify the signature but this always fails.  Here is the complete code of the client part:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\public.key", "mypassword");
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;

    string payload = "Hello world!!";

    byte[] encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload), false);

    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect("192.168.1.57", 2002);

    NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

    ns.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
    ns.ReadTimeout = 2000;
    byte[] rx = new byte[5000];
    int bytesRead = ns.Read(rx, 0, rx.Length);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        int keySizeBytes = rsa.KeySize >> 3;
        if (bytesRead > keySizeBytes)
        {
            byte[] signedMessage = new byte[bytesRead - keySizeBytes];
            Array.Copy(rx, keySizeBytes, signedMessage, 0, signedMessage.Length);
            Array.Resize<byte>(ref rx, keySizeBytes);

            if (rsa.VerifyData(signedMessage, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), rx))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Verified OK");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not verified");
            }
        }
    }
    client.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Is there something I am missing that I need to do to be able to verify the data on the client side?

Comment: Are you sure that you've received the entire message when you attempt to verify? You're processing the data if you receive more than `keySizeBytes`, but make no check to ensure you've received *all* the data that the server sent (indeed, your client has no way to know how much data it should be expecting to receive).

Comment: I have checked, and all the data is there.  I know the socket code is weak in terms of ensuring all the data is transferred, but this is just for test purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `RSA_sign` incorrectly - per the [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_sign.html) (emphasis mine):

> RSA_sign() signs the **message digest** m of size m_len using the private key rsa as specified in PKCS #1 v2.0

In other words, you must hash your message first, and then pass the *message hash* to `RSA_sign`. It should then be verifiable in .NET.

The following change should work:

```
unsigned char* hash = SHA1((unsigned char *)reply, strlen(reply), NULL);

if (RSA_sign(NID_sha1, hash, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, signature, &siglen, privateKey))
{
    ...
```